# OOP in python (related to scrapy)

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, architecture

The question is how to share data between objecs in a safe and maintainable manner.

Example:
I've build the scrapy application which spawns numerous spiders. Although each spider is connected to separate pipeline object, I need to compare and sort the data between different pipelines (e.g. I need outputs sorted by different item attributes: prices, date etc.), so I need some shared data area. The same applies to spiders themselves (e.g. I need to count maximum total requests).
The first implementation used class variables to shared data between between spiders/pipelines and instance variables for each object.

```
class MyPipeline(object):
max_price = 0

def process_item(self, item, spider):
if item['price'] > max_price : 
 max_price = item['price']
```

(The actual structures are more complex) Then I thought out that having a bunch of statics is not OOP and the next solution is to have the  private class data for each class and use to store values:

```
class MyPipelineData:
def __init__(self):
   self.max_price = 0

class SpidersData:
  def __init___(self, total_requests, pipeline_data):
    self.total_requests = total_requests
    self.pipeline_data = pipeline_data #the shared data between pipelines

class MyPipeline(object):
pipeline_data = None

def process_item(self, item, spider):
  if _data is None:  
     _data = spider.data.pipeline_data  #the shared data between pipelines  
  if item['price'] > _data.max_price : 
   _data.max_price = item['price']

 class Spider(scrapy.spider):
 def __init__(self, spider_data):
   self._data = spider_data
  # and the same object of SpiderData is passed to all spiders
```

Now I have one instance of data shared between all pipeplines (and the same for spiders). Am I generally correct with this? Should I apply same OOP approaches in python as in C++ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, the approach you are proposing is to keep a reference from each object to a shared object that captures all of the shared data, and and I think this is perfectly fine, especially if you name it appropriately so that its name suggests it's being shared, for readability.

Also, you're hiding the internals of the shared object and encapsulating them inside methods such as process_item(), which I think is really important for maintainability (because changes in the internals of the shared object don't have to affect any other object).

But I'm not sure about the way you are bootstrapping (i.e. initializing) this shared object. You have these two lines

```
if _data is None:
  _data = ...
```

which are a little surprising. I didn't quite understand what _data is and where it is defined. Also pipeline_data is assigned to None and never assigned to anything else, so I'm not sure what you meant there.

If possible, I would prefer to see a function called create_spiders() that creates the shared object, and then creates the different spiders one by one, giving them a reference to the shared object. This makes the logic very clear.

---

However, in the special case that you want the shared object to be a singleton, I would consider making it a static object in some module that you name appropriately, maybe Globals.py. And then inside your Spider code you would see things like

```
import Globals

class SpiderData:

def update(self):
  self.data.price = 200
  Globals.spiders_data_collector.process(self.data)
```

Inside the module Globals you would initialize the object spiders_data_collector. I think this requires less code, and this is also important for maintainability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. pipeline_data is meant to be _data. Do you think the fact I need one instance of shared data is enought to make it singleton? Look like the approach of creating it with e.g. create_spiders from the main control branch is safer.